# error: kafka.producer.Partitioner does not take parameters

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I am writing a simple producer program to write data to a quorum of 6 kafka instances. I Looked up source code example on [kafka docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example) and also from [a book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/9781782167938/5dot-writing-producers/ch05s03_html). I appropriately modified *metadata.broker.list* and *partitioner.class*. When I try to compile the project, I get the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project mud_kafka_test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] /Users/aojha/kafka/kafka_test/src/main/java/com/kafka_test/SimplePartitioner.java:[8,53] type kafka.producer.Partitioner does not take parameters

Thoughts?